# How to make Jbuilder to always return times in UTC?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, datetime, timezone, jbuilder

I have an app where a user submits several dates and times without timezone info. A controller receives these datetimes, interprets them as datetimes in the Pacific zone, and saves them into the database in UTC. Then the controller returns a JSON built with Jbuilder which contains these datetimes. I want these datetimes to be returned in UTC, but without having to convert each of them to UTC explicitly. Is there a way to specify this conversion in Jbuilder globally?

Here's some sample code to illustrate the question:

```
# ActiveRecord has the default configuration, i.e. UTC

Time.use_zone('Pacific Time (US & Canada)') do
  p = Party.new(:started_at => "2014-07-27 15:00")
  p.save
end
Jbuilder.encode do |json|
  json.started_at p.started_at.utc
  # => "{\"started_at\":\"2014-07-27T22:00:00.000Z\"}"
  # Without .utc
  # => "{\"started_at\":\"2014-07-27T15:00:00.000-07:00\"}"
end
```

How to get JBuilder to return the datetimes (originally in the Pacific Time zone) in UTC without having to add `.utc` explicitly on each field?

Comment: Not sure if there is a global way or not, but in general, it's not a good idea to handle this kind of thing globally.  Different parts of an application may indeed need to work with different time zone behavior.

Comment: What's your default time zone in Rails?

Comment: @MichalSzyndel `config.time_zone` is not explicitly set, so it's the default, i.e. UTC